# Opencart theme not showing

Tags: themes, opencart

I need some help with this issue. I've downloaded opencart (2.1.0) and I am trying to change the theme. I've followed the instructions (control panel > settings > store > template ...) and it is supposed to be done successfully, but nothing is changing at the frontend. I have checked at my database and the config_template is set to my new theme, but I see no changes. What is happening here? How can I display the new theme?

Thank you, hope me to be helped!

Comment: Share me your admin details .

Comment: What do you mean with admin details?Is not a real shop, I am just making this like a test, would be at localhost

Comment: I mean, is not even online in a domain or something

Comment: Thenn you might be doing something wrong

Comment: Here is the helpful answer for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097531/why-is-opencart-2-3-custom-theme-not-showing/40140155#40140155

Answer (score 0):

To Activate new theme in Opencart,

1. Open folder **UPLOAD** from purchased archive and upload all content inside it (folders image, catalog, admin, etc.) to your installed OpenCart directory
2. Go to your **OpenCart admin panel > System > Settings > Edit**. Click Store tab and choose Your Theme for "Template" option.
3. Click on **Save**. This action will activate your new theme.

I hope this helps. You can test some [free OpenCart templates](http:///www.magikcommerce.com/opencart/themes/free/)